# What is Dubikajtis Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, functional-equations

Recently I was studying functional equations from the book *Functional equations and how to solve them* by G.Small. In which for Problem 24 of Chapter 3 the author has stated (in solution) that the problem can ask be solved by Dubikajtis theorem, but when I was searching in internet the theorem was some kind of stuff related to mathematical logic, but how we can we use it here or is there any such theorem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference you are looking for is the following paper:

Lech Dubikajtis, [Sur certaines équations fonctionnelles vérifiées par la fonction $\varphi(x)=x^{-1}$](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/annales-polonici-mathematici/all/22/2/97193/sur-certaines-equations-fonctionnelles-verifiees-par-la-fonction-x-x-1) , Annales Polonici Mathematici 22 (1969), 199-205.

He shows that $\varphi(x)=x^{-1}$ is the unique continuous function which satisfies this system of functional equations for $x>0$,
$$\begin{cases}
f(f(x))=x\\
f(x+1)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+1}
\end{cases}
$$
The pdf is free to download.